# Win10 laptop randomly freezes, some texts are missing after

Tags: windows-10, freeze, hp-laptop

Laptop is an HP Omen (2016) with Win10 installed and updated regularly. For the past months, it freezes my programs seemingly randomly. While the program is frozen I can switch to some other programs usually and use it, but it's likely that program2 will freeze in some seconds too during this time. The freezes can last for some seconds to minutes. After the freezes are over, Windows and other programs starts to [fail displaying some texts randomly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gEPs.jpg).

I've run the Win built in memory and disk checks. The memory check was done very quickly with no issues, the chkdsk got stuck on 17% for hours so I left it to run overnight and it finished too. The freezes continued with no noticeable change.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: Also, check *Details* in *Task Manager* -- leave it open, sort by CPU usage, and see if a particular process is using all CPU time when the issue occurs.

Comment: [Here](https://i.gyazo.com/555cb3cb26e7876d8ea1d03c621c3307.png) is the HDD SMART status. I see some weird numbers but I think the HDD is fine? I will check if I can see anything that has high CPU usage while the freeze occurs.